# RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout, из за этого количество вопросов увеличивается

Tags: java, android

RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout, из за этого наверное количество вопросов увеличивается каждый раз после перехода между категориями.
Дело в том что поле клика на эти появившиеся вопросы приложение сворачивается и выходит такая вот ошибка:

```
01-19 19:45:42.542 1382-1382/com.example.androidquiz E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

Помогите пожалуйста.

[image: До перехода]
[image: Когда возвращаюсь]

**content_questions:**

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            tools:context=".QuestionActivity"
            tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_question">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:id="@+id/grid_answer"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_question_right"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/grid_answer"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:text="0/30"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:textSize="24dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_timer"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:text="20:00"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:textSize="24dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



            </RelativeLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
                    app:tabMode="scrollable"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

QuestionActivity:

```
public class QuestionActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    int time_play = Common.TOTAL_TIME;
    boolean isAnswerModeView = false;
    CountDownTimer countDownTimer;

    TextView txt_right_answer, txt_timer;

    RecyclerView answer_sheet_view;
    AnswerSheetAdapter answerSheetAdapter;


    ViewPager viewPager;
    TabLayout tabLayout;


    @Override protected void onDestroy() {
        if (Common.countDownTimer != null)
            Common.countDownTimer.cancel();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_question);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(Common.selectedCategory.getName());
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        //First we need take question from DB

        takeQuestion();

        if (Common.questionList.size() > 0) {

            //Show TexeView right answer and text View Timer

            txt_right_answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_question_right);
            txt_timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_timer);

            txt_timer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txt_right_answer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txt_right_answer.setText(new StringBuilder(String.format("%d/%d",Common.right_answer_count,Common.questionList.size())));

            countTimer();


            //View
            answer_sheet_view = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.answer_sheet);
            answer_sheet_view = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.grid_answer);
            answer_sheet_view.setHasFixedSize(true);

            if (Common.questionList.size() > 5) // IF QUESTION LIST HAVE SIZE > 5, WE WILL sperate 2 ROWs
                answer_sheet_view.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, Common.questionList.size() / 2));
            answerSheetAdapter = new AnswerSheetAdapter(this, Common.answerSheetList);
            answer_sheet_view.setAdapter(answerSheetAdapter);

            viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
            tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);


                genFragmentList();

                //Event

            viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

                int SCRILLING_RIGHT = 0;
                int SCRILLING_LEFT = 1;
                int SCRILLING_UNDERTERMINED = 2;

                int currentScrollDirection = 2;

                private void setScrollingDirection(float positionOffset) {
                    if((1-positionOffset) >= 0.5)
                        this.currentScrollDirection = SCRILLING_RIGHT;
                    else if((1-positionOffset) <= 0.5)
                        this.currentScrollDirection = SCRILLING_LEFT;
                }

                private boolean isScrollDirectionUndetermined() {
                    return currentScrollDirection == SCRILLING_UNDERTERMINED;
                }

                private boolean isScrollingRight() {
                    return currentScrollDirection == SCRILLING_RIGHT;
                }

                private boolean isScrollingLEft() {
                    return currentScrollDirection == SCRILLING_LEFT;
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i1) /**/{
                    if(isScrollDirectionUndetermined())
                        setScrollingDirection(v);

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int i) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

                }
            });

                QuestionFragmentAdapter questionFragmentAdapter = new QuestionFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                        this, Common.fragmentList);
            viewPager.setAdapter(questionFragmentAdapter);

            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

            }
        }

        private void genFragmentList() {
            for (int i=0; i<Common.answerSheetList.size();i++)
            {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("index",i);
                QuestionFragment fragment= new QuestionFragment();
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);

                Common.fragmentList.add(fragment);
            }
        }

        private void countTimer() {
            if (Common.countDownTimer == null)
            {
                Common.countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(Common.TOTAL_TIME,1000) {
                    @Override
                public void onTick(long l) {

                    txt_timer.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d",
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(l),
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(l) -
                                    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(l))));
                    time_play-=1000;

                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
//                    finish game

                }
            }.start();
        }
        else
        {
            Common.countDownTimer.cancel();
            Common.countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(Common.TOTAL_TIME,1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long l) {
                    txt_timer.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d",
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(l),
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(l) -
                                    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(l))));
                    time_play-=1000;

                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
//                    finish game

                }
            }.start();
        }
    }

    private void takeQuestion() {
        Common.questionList = DBHelper.getInstance(this).getQuestionByCategory(Common.selectedCategory.getId());
        if (Common.questionList.size() == 0) {
            //if no question
            new MaterialStyledDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Oppps")
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_sentiment_very_dissatisfied_black_24dp)
                    .setDescription("We do not have any questions in this " + Common.selectedCategory.getName() + " category")
                    .setPositiveText("OK")
                    .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            finish();
                        }
                    }).show();
        } else
            for (int i = 0; i < Common.questionList.size(); i++) {
                Common.answerSheetList.add(new CurrentQuestion(i, Common.ANSWER_TYPE.NO_ANSWER));
            }

    }

    @Override public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.question, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody") @Override public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_tools) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: какая-то странная логика у вас, вам нужно адаптер либо обновить после добавления вопросов, либо сетить после того как все вопросы добавлены, а вы его сетите и объявляете в самом начале когда еще вопросов нету.

Comment: @Andrew Андрей, а не могли бы править код, я не совсем вам понял, просто я только начал и не совсем понимаю вас.

Comment: что значит править код в вашем понимании? я указал где возможно ошибка, не очень понятно как оно у вас работает просто :(

Comment: @Andrew Я не совсем вас понял, вот в чем проблема. Я только начал этим заниматься и не все понимаю вас. Я вот это не совсем понял "вам нужно адаптер либо обновить после добавления вопросов, либо сетить после того как все вопросы добавлены, а вы его сетите и объявляете в самом начале когда еще вопросов нету " и я не очень понимаю где я наложал в коде?